# ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException when using @EmbeddedKafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

Once I add @EmbeddedKafka to an integration test I see the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedKafka': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.customizeContext(EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextCustomizerAdapter.initialize(SpringBootContextLoader.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:626)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:126)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:258)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:253)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:254)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:112)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1826)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.createZkClient$1(KafkaServer.scala:364)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:387)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:207)
    at kafka.utils.TestUtils$.createServer(TestUtils.scala:142)
    at kafka.utils.TestUtils.createServer(TestUtils.scala)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
```

Comment: You need to show your test code and configuration.

Comment: I have the same issue. Spring boot 2.2.7, kafka client 2.3.1. Only trying to make embedded kafka up and running (just context test).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring boot 2.2.x
you have to explicitly use spring kafka 2.4.6 (at least in test)

```
testImplementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.4.6.RELEASE'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:2.4.6.RELEASE'
```

and also explicitly set your kafka client version to 2.3.1 (in gradle.properties file):

```
kafka.version=2.4.1
```

Comment: spring boot 2.2.x supports two kafka client versions. So most probably dependency version incomparibility issues.